# Grid data formating in View or ViewModel?

Tags: performance, mvvm, infragistics

My current task involves using Infragistics grid to show large amounts of data, hence scrolling performance is critical (please don’t ask why it was designed so). Infragistics provides CellValuePresenter style which considerably reduces the number of visual components in the grid and hence improves performance, although with a trade-off of data formatting provided by the control. I am considering using Linq to format the data in the ViewModel but as someone in my team mentioned that this approach would breach the MVVM 'rules'. What would you do if the performance of the grid is critical, would you consider moving the data formatting logic in the VM?

Comment: What formatting are you doing?  If you are formatting based on a culture, then doing the formatting in the ViewModel will work well.  If you allow editing then you may want to consider not formatting the data and use the editors of the grid to provide the formatting.  Also since virtualization is used only the cells in View will actually have a CellValuePresenter created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well since the VM should provide some data and the business logic, IMHO it's totally correct that the view is formating the values, because it should interpret the VMs. Additionally, the value format is the definition of how the values visual representation looks like, so...

Consider, a new requirement, you should also provide the application in another culture. The data doesn't change. You only have to improve the view...